# What is the shortcut key for starting the slideshow from the selected or active slide?

Tags: slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint

What is the shortcut key for starting the slideshow from the selected or active slide?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To start a presentation from the current slide:

- in PowerPoint 2003 or later, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
- in PowerPoint X/Macintosh, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

To start a presentation from the beginning:

- in PowerPoint for Windows, press <kbd>F5</kbd>
- in PowerPoint X/Mac, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Mine is Microsoft Powerpoint 2002 and Shift+F5 is not working in it :(

Comment: I installed 2007 and now it is working.

Comment: I have a multi-monitor Windows setup, and F5 and/or Shift+F5 both launch as one monitor with presentation, but also with one with presenter view.

How do you just show the presentation without the presenter view?

Comment: ALT, W, D does show Reading View though. This somewhat solves my question above :)

Comment: And how can you jump to the next page without going through all the animations?

Comment: @skan: That's a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint 2016 has the following keyboard shortcuts to play a slideshow.

From the **current** slide:

- Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>

From the **first** slide:

- Windows: <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd>

References: [Windows](https://blogs.office.com/2015/08/13/10-little-known-keyboard-shortcuts-for-editing-in-powerpoint/) and [Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-PowerPoint-2016-for-Mac-F25F92B3-B0A8-4C60-AEC8-954B72AA81AD)

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Impress <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> works fine.