# Make current slide of PPT fullscreen

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the shortcut key for starting the slideshow from the selected or active slide?](https://superuser.com/questions/182091/what-is-the-shortcut-key-for-starting-the-slideshow-from-the-selected-or-active)

When you press <kbd>F5</kbd> while going through a Powerpoint PPT, it fullscreens the PPT but goes to the 1st slide. I want to see the current slide fullscreen - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shift + F5 is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the same for all versions, but pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> will start at the current slide in 2010.

There is also this icon on the status bar which will do the same thing.

[image]